# converting a list of tuples to list of dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to convert a list of tuple to a list of dictionary with a data that looks like this:

```
data =[
    ('base-certificate', 60, 3, 2022), 
    ('case-certificate', 1, 3, 2022), 
    ('standard-certificate', 7, 3, 2022),
    ('base-certificate', 50, 4, 2022), 
    ('case-certificate', 80, 4, 2022), 
    ('standard-certificate', 10, 4, 2022)
]
```

The last two numbers are dates representing month and year, this means that there can also be data for April(4), May(5), etc. and it would be unique. so to create a date object in javascript these two numbers are needed preferably in a list [3, 2022].

I would like an output that looks like this:

```
[
    {x:[3, 2022], base: 60, case:1, standard: 7}, 
    {x:[4, 2022], base: 50, case:80, standard: 10} 
]
```

I tried using the defaultdict from the collection library:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data=defaultdict(dict) 

for a, b, c, d in se:
    if "x" not in data[c, d]:
        data[c, d]['x'] = [c,d]
    data[c, d][a] = b
        
print(data)
```

The result of the code was:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {(3, 2022): {'x': [3, 2022], 'base-certificate': 60, 'case-certificate': 1, 'standard-certificate': 7}, (4, 2022): {'x': [4, 2022], 'base-certificate': 50, 'case-certificate': 80, 'standard-certificate': 10}})
```

it was close but am missing something.
Please what is the best approach in this case? and what am I am doing wrong, Thank you for your kind response.

Comment: Your expected output seems to be a list of dicts but you create a single master dict...

Comment: because it will make it easy to show in a graph, yes but then I realized that i was only transform it for one month it is helpful but not flexible enough when you have one than one month

Comment: Is your list of tuples guaranteed to be in groups of three - i.e., base/case/standard ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution using `itertools.groupby`.
If the dates are sorted you can use `groupby` directly on the data, if not, you should sort by date first.

```py
from itertools import groupby

result = []
for key, group in groupby(data, lambda x: (x[2], x[3])):
    r = {'x': key}
    for a, b, _, _ in group:
        r[a.partition('-')[0]] = b
    result.append(r)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'x': (3, 2022), 'base': 60, 'case': 1, 'standard': 7}, {'x': (4, 2022), 'base': 50, 'case': 80, 'standard': 10}]
```

Comment: Isn't grouping by date risky?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
data = [
    ("base-certificate", 60, 3, 2022),
    ("case-certificate", 1, 3, 2022),
    ("standard-certificate", 7, 3, 2022),
    ("base-certificate", 50, 4, 2022),
    ("case-certificate", 80, 4, 2022),
    ("standard-certificate", 10, 4, 2022),
]

out = {}
for name, val, month, year in data:
    out.setdefault((month, year), {}).update(
        {"x": [month, year], name.split("-")[0]: val}
    )

print(list(out.values()))
```

Prints:

```
[
    {"x": [3, 2022], "base": 60, "case": 1, "standard": 7},
    {"x": [4, 2022], "base": 50, "case": 80, "standard": 10},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
data =[
('base-certificate', 60, 3, 2022), 
('case-certificate', 1, 3, 2022), 
('standard-certificate', 7, 3, 2022),
('base-certificate', 50, 4, 2022), 
('case-certificate', 80, 4, 2022), 
('standard-certificate', 10, 4, 2022)
]

# Initialize an empty dictionary to store output
certificates_by_year = {}

for certificate_type, quantity, month, year in data:
    if (month, year) not in certificates_by_year:
        certificates_by_year[(month, year)] = {'x': [month, year]}
        certificates_by_year[(month, year)][certificate_type.replace('-certificate','')] = quantity

# Convert the dictionary to the desired list format
result = list(certificates_by_year.values())

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[
 {'x': [3, 2022], 'base': 60, 'case': 1, 'standard': 7},
 {'x': [4, 2022], 'base': 50, 'case': 80, 'standard': 10}
]
```